# while setting variable showing error in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have stored procedure like this:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test1]  
   @startdate datetime(100),  
   @enddate datetime(100)
   set  date1 = CONVERT(datetime, @startdate + ' 00:01:00', 120)
   set   date2 = CONVERT(datetime, @enddate + ' 00:23:59', 120)  
as  
begin  
  select t.PlateNo 
  from Transaction_tbl t  
  WHERE dtime between @date1 + ' 00.01.00.00' 
    AND @date2 + ' 23:59.59.00'  
end
```

While executing this getting two error messages

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.*
>
> *Must declare the scalar variable `@date1`*

Comment: you have set date1 and in query used @date1 (vs date1) - is not the same variable. Hope this helps

Comment: i given set @date1 ,,then also getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test1]  
   @startdate varchar(100),  
   @enddate varchar(100)
as  
begin  
   declare @date1 datetime = CONVERT(datetime, @startdate + ' 00:01:00', 120);
   declare @date2 datetime = CONVERT(datetime, @enddate + ' 00:23:59', 120);

   select t.PlateNo 
   from Transaction_tbl t  
   WHERE dtime between @date1 AND @date2; 
end;
```

However, I think you would be better off in following the advice in my answer on your previous question and passing in the parameters as `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test1]  
   @startdate varchar(100),  
   @enddate varchar(100)
as 
declare @date1 datetime
declare @date2 datetime
   set  @date1 = CONVERT(datetime, @startdate + ' 00:01:00', 120)
   set   @date2 = CONVERT(datetime, @enddate + ' 00:23:59', 120)  

begin  
  select t.PlateNo 
  from Transaction_tbl t  
  WHERE dtime between @date1 + ' 00.01.00.00' 
    AND @date2 + ' 23:59.59.00'  
end
```